# How to add a new key value pair in existing JSON object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var json = {
    "workbookInformation": {
        "version": "9.1",
        "source-platform": "win"
    },
    "datasources1": {
        ...
    },
    "datasources2": {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to add new key pair under `workbookInformation` like

```
var json={
    "workbookInformation": {
         "version": "9.1",
         "source-platform": "win",
         "new_key":"new_value"
    },
    "datasources1": {
        ...
    },
    "datasources2": {
        ...
    }
}
```

`json['new_key'] = 'new_value';` adds the new key but I want it under "workbookInformation"

Comment: `json.workbookInformation['new_key'] = 'new_value'` this should do

Comment: FYI, that's not JSON, that's a plain ol' javscript object - JSON is a string, you'd have one heck of a time trying to add a new key to JSON, whoa nelly

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**There are two ways for adding new key value pair to Json Object  in JS**

```
var jsObj = {
    "workbookInformation": {
        "version": "9.1",
        "source-platform": "win"
    },
    "datasources1": {

    },
    "datasources2": {

    }
}
```

**1.Add New Property using dot(.)**

```
jsObj.workbookInformation.NewPropertyName ="Value of New Property";
```

**2.Add New Property specifying index like in an arrays .**

```
jsObj["workbookInformation"]["NewPropertyName"] ="Value of New Property";
```

**Finally**

```
 json = JSON.stringify(jsObj);
 console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to add new key and value to each of the key of json object and then you can use the following code else you can use the code of other answers -

```
Object.keys(json).map(
  function(object){
    json[object]["newKey"]='newValue'
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
 const Districts=[
  {
    "District": "Gorkha",
    "Headquarters": "Gorkha",
    "Area": "3,610",
    "Population": "271,061"
  },
  {
    "District": "Lamjung",
    "Headquarters": "Besisahar",
    "Area": "1,692",
    "Population": "167,724"
  }
]
Districts.map(i=>i.Country="Nepal")
console.log(Districts)
```

If you have JSON Array Object Instead of a simple JSON.

```
const Districts= [
  {
    "District": "Gorkha",
    "Headquarters": "Gorkha",
    "Area": "3,610",
    "Population": "271,061"
  },
  {
    "District": "Lamjung",
    "Headquarters": "Besisahar",
    "Area": "1,692",
    "Population": "167,724"
  }
]
```

Then you can map through it to add new keys.

```
Districts.map(i=>i.Country="Nepal");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your object is only a JavaScript object and not JSON. You can either use `brackets notation` or the dot notation like

```
json["workbookInformation"]["new_key"] = "new_value";
```

```js
var json={
    "workbookInformation": {
     "version": "9.1",
    "source-platform": "win"
    }
    
    }

json.workbookInformation.new_key = 'new_value';
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
json.workbookInformation.new_key = 'new_value';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json.workbookInformation.key = value;
```